# Библиотека обёртка над JDBC Java EE

Tags: java, jdbc

Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли какие-то обёртки над JDBC для удобной работы?

Гуглил так ничего и не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Если EE only, то jpa. В частности посмотрите в строну hibernate - это ORM фреймворк реализующей JPA. 
Тут можете подробнее почитать.
http://hibernate.org/

Answer (score 0):

Есть. Под обертка над БД обычно понимают ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) которая связывает сущности вашей СУБД и объекты вашей бизнес-логики. Для ЕЕ, как ответили выше, нужно использоваться ORM соответствующую спецификации JPA. В 99% случаев для этого используют Hibernate. 
Если же жестких требований на JPA соответствие нет и хочется работать с СУБД проще, то можно использовать MyBatis, которая очень проста в использовании, но при этом имеет очень мощные возможности.